# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void keyset() from the type Id

Tags: apex, error, visualstudiocode

I think is something very small, but i dont what can be, i am new in apex class

```
  List<Deal_Registration__c> deal = new List<Deal_Registration__c>();
        if (Deal_Registration__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()) {
          deal = [
            SELECT
              id,
              Name,
              Product_Platform__c,
              Opportunity__c,
              Deal_Registration_Group__c,
            FROM Deal_Registration__c
            WHERE Opportunity__c IN :opp.keySet()
            ];
        } else {
          LogHelper.log('');
          throw new NoAccessException();
        }
        return deal;
      }
```

Comment: `keySet` is not a method you can call on `opp`. If you're new to Apex, please go through tutorials and documentation. To start: [Apex basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If `opp` is of type ID (a singleton)

  ```
   WHERE Opportunity__c = :opp
  ```
- If `opp` is a collection (list or set) of `Id`

  ```
   WHERE Opportunity__c IN :opp
  ```
- If `opp` is a map defined as `Map<Id,someType>`

  ```
   WHERE Opportunity__c IN :opp.keySet()
  ```
- If `opp` is a *list* of Opportunity SObjects

  ```
   WHERE Opportunity__c IN :opp
  ```

The thing to remember is to use good variable names. I prefer my lists and collections to always be plurals - like `opps`; singletons are singular-named, and Maps are named like `someFoosBySomeKey` - e.g. `opposByOppId`

Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm